# Installing mod_security

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-security

I have apache and suphp running. How hard is it to install modsecurity? Also, where can I find some light weight/generic rule-sets to not bog apache down?

Comment: The [OWASP Core Ruleset](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to compile mod_security and load the module into Apache.

There are also packages available to install on your OS.
https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_security+rpm

and I think default rules will do fine.

mod_security installation guide:
http://modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/02-installation.html